# How do I export a function for importing in ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Puzzled what I am doing wrong here in node v10.5.0

```
[hendry@t480s learn2]$ node --experimental-modules main.mjs
(node:23920) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///tmp/learn2/main.mjs:1
import {hello} from 'module' // or './module'
        ^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'module' does not provide an export named 'hello'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:80:21)
[hendry@t480s learn2]$ cat main.mjs
import {hello} from 'module' // or './module'
let val = hello() // val is "Hello";

console.log('hi there')

console.log(val)
[hendry@t480s learn2]$ cat module.mjs
export function hello() {
  return "Hello";
}

export default hello
```

Comment: Did you try `from './module'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's only one function in the module, then you can do:

```
export default function hello() {
    return "Hello";
}
```

And import it like this:

```
import hello from './module'
```

You can choose a name when importing a module that you exported with `export default`:

```
import greeting from './module'
```

You can't export `const` `let` and `var` using `export default`

If there are multiple functions in the module you can do this:

```
export function hello() {
    return "Hello";
}

export function bye() {
    return "Bye";
}
```

or

```
function hello() {
    return "Hello";
}

function bye() {
    return "Bye";
}

export { hello, bye };
```

and import a function this way:

```
import { hello } from './module'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello is a default export

In react for example, React is the default export, since that is often the only part that you need. You don't always Component, so that's a named export that you can import when needed.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react`';
```

Comment: But `export function hello` is a named export, right? (I would've thought the module has both default export and named export)

Answer (score 0):

import `hello from 'module'` since you export it as default.
Exports can be named export(several per module), default export(one per module), a mix of both named and default.
named export is

```
    export function square(x) {
      return x * x;
    }

    export function diag(x, y) {
      return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
    }

    import { square, diag } from '---';
```

in default export, we write like, `export default function(){}` and used when there is only one export in a file. Note the function has no name.

```
    //------ myFunc.js ------
    export default function () { ... };

    //------ main1.js ------
    import myFunc from 'myFunc';
    myFunc();
```

A cheatsheet here: https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20146827)

Comment: @PankajMakwana sure! i will update the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can export only one variable or function or anything as default. then you can import wherever you want.

```
export default function hello(){
    return "Hello";
}
```

or, export the function , at the last of the file.

```
function hello(){
    return "Hello";
}

export default hello;
```

and then, you can import as,

```
import hello from '../module.js'
```